# Code Templates in MonoDevelop 2.0

Tags: monodevelop, code-templates

I'd like to create some custom templates in MonoDevelop 2.0 (under Ubuntu) but am not finding the process as intuitive as I'd like. Does anyone know where in templates are stored? In what format?

Kindness,

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MD 2.0 they're stored in a single XML file in `~/.config/MonoDevelop/monodevelop-templates.xml` In MD 2.2b1 they're stored as individual files in `~/.config/MonoDevelop/templates/code/`

MD 2.2 has much better code template features. There's support for linked and editable regions, "surround with" templates, and the code template editor has been rewritten.

Answer (score 1):

On OS X 10.7 and MonoDevelop 2.8, they are individual files that live here:

```
~/Library/MonoDevelop-Unity-2.8/Snippets/
```

Edit: They have now moved to here:

```
~/Library/MonoDevelop-Unity-4.0/Snippets
```